# how Npgsql.EntityFramework support Spatial data

Tags: postgresql, c#

I am using Npgsql.EntityFramework + EntityFramework6.My database is postgresql. I Added to my C# project with this tutorial :

> https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/Visual-Studio-Design-Time-Support---DDEX-Provider

It works well. The problem is this that when I have a field of spatial data like point and polygon it cannot add that field to model. How can I solve this problem?